# Updating user fields in Active Directory with ldap_mod_replace

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to update the mobile field for a user in Active Directory but I keep getting the following error. I have been trying to solve this for hours. It's probably something simple.

> Warning: ldap_mod_replace(): Modify: Invalid syntax in
>   /var/www/php_builders/admin/user_update/user_update_action.php on line
>   183

When I output the array, the mobile number shows up. its not empty.

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
$adconn = ldap_connect("ldap://earth.example.com") or die("Couldn't connect to AD!");
$set = ldap_set_option($adconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_get_option($adconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, $value); 
$DN = 'CN=itcoopadmin,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com';
$ldap_bind = ldap_bind($adconn, $DN, "**********");
$dn = trim($_POST['dn']);
$mobile = trim($_POST['mobile']);

if(!empty($mobile)) {
    $AD_mobile = AD_format($mobile);
    $DB_mobile = DB_format($mobile);
    $attributes['mobile'] = $AD_mobile;
} else {
    $DELETEattrs["mobile"] = array();
    $DELETEattrs = array();
}


$replace=ldap_mod_replace($adconn, $dn, $attributes); // Line 183, where the error is getting triggered

$disconnect = ldap_unbind($adconn);
```

Comment: Does the mobile field already exist for your user? If not, you need to do `ldap_mod_add`.

Comment: the mobile field already exists

Comment: I would recommend throwing in an `if($ldap_bind){...}` then just to make sure the problem doesn't exist there

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference :(

Comment: The only thing I have left...We have `$replace = ldap_mod_replace($con, "uid=$uid ou=people...", $attr);` I wonder if there was an issue passing the `dn` in that way when this was set up?  If your organization doesn't have too many different `ou` maybe this could work for you guys? Also, we are using it for RHEL, might make a difference there too.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the attribute has to be given as array. So I'd suggest that you try this:

```
$attributes['mobile'] = array($AD_mobile);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone is still looking, try:

```
$attributes['mobile'][0] = $AD_mobile;
```